# How to get keyboard height WITHOUT relying on notifications

Tags: ios, ipad

I know how to set up an NSNotification observer to detect when the keyboard shows/hides. From this I can get the height of the keyboard.  But what happens if the device is rotated while the keyboard is still showing?

Is there a way to get the height of the keyboard in this new state? Since the keyboard is still showing a new notification will not be triggered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You still have to use NSNotificationCenter, but you have to observe a different key. The key you're looking for is [UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) which according to the docs is posted immediately after a change in the keyboard’s frame.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. It gets called after both the KeyboardDidShow _and_ KeyboardDidHide notification.

Answer (score 5):

On **iOS 6+**, if you've registered to receive the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, your selector will be called called again when the orientation changes.

This is the notification that Apple uses in their sample code for [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), however, when using this notification, their calculation is wrong when calculating the keyboard height in landscape mode:

```
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Replace the above with this:

```
// Works in both portrait and landscape mode
CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect toView:nil];

CGSize kbSize = kbRect.size;
```

Comment: `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` will not be called on rotation if the keyboard is already shown.

Comment: I can attest that the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` does not get called upon device rotation which is why I had to post this question.

Comment: @SteveBarden, apparently this is only true on iOS 6+. I updated my answer.